# sesame http repository connection - begin()

Tags: sesame

I have the following code for creating connection and starting a transaction:

```
org.openrdf.repository.RepositoryConnection con = repo.getConnection(); 
con.begin();
```

The line con.begin() produces the following error:

```
No signature of method: org.openrdf.repository.http.HTTPRepositoryConnection.begin() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: wait(), find(), wait(long), is(java.lang.Object), print(java.io.PrintWriter), print(java.lang.Object)
```

The call is legitimate, I don't know how I could fix this. I considered not using the call, but was told the call is necessary to keep commit from becoming automatic. I'm not sure what is the best solution here, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this is an Apache Camel question as we do not have such code you show above. It indicates its from this project: http://rdf4j.org/

Comment: You are right, I'm moving it under sesame

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using def con =, instead of org.openrdf.repository.RepositoryConnection.
Also, I had a conflict for three different jar files (httpclient, httpcore, httpmime), removing older copies of them solved the issue.